# proving that if $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ then $x=y$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, real-numbers

Here's what the authors of a textbook that I've been following argue:

> Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $x \le y$ and $y ≤ x$. We claim
>   that $x = y$. If false, then either, $x < y$ or $y < x$ by law of
>   *trichotomy*. Assume that we have $x < y$. Since $y ≤ x$, either $x = y$ or $y < x$. Neither can be true, since we assumed $x \not= y$ and
>   hence concluded $x < y$ from the first inequality $x ≤ y$. Hence we
>   conclude that the second inequality cannot be true, a contradiction.
>   Thus our assumption that $x \not= y$ is not tenable.

My argument is as follows: We assume that $x \le y$ and $y ≤ x$. Suppose $x\not=y$. Then $x \le y$ and $y ≤ x$ reduces to $x < y$ and $y < x$. But both inequalities  $x < y$ and $y < x$ cannot hold together at the same time due to *trichotomy*. Thus we achieved a contradiction to our hypothesis. Is this argument correct?

I need a clarification on proof done by the authors. They say "Assume that we have $x < y$" and on another line they say "hence concluded $x < y$ from the first inequality $x ≤ y$". Did they deduce it or assume it?

Comment: Yours is fine and much better written than the cited proof. I agree that theirs is not easy to follow word for word, but the intended reasoning seems to be the same as yours.

Comment: Basically they state their assumption $x<y$ and then later instead of saying “cause we’re assuming $x<y$“ they act as if their assumption was actually $x\le y,$ and procede to prove $x<y$ from that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen this still baffles me. Assume some proposition $P$ and prove $P$?

Comment: They're argument is the exact same as yours.  Whereas you took $x \le y$ and $x \ne y$ to immediate imply $x < y$, they went strict deduction mode:  $x\le y$  means $x< y$ or $x =y$ and as $x \ne y$ we can't have $x=y$ so $x< y$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You are being dyslexic.  The assume $x <y$ and then look at $y \le x$.  (NOT, as you state, $x \le y$).  As they *know* $y\le x$ (that was a given) they know either $y< x$ (NOT, as you state, $x < y$) and $y=x$ and both *contradict* $x< y$.  So the assumption $x < y$ must be wrong.  So the only option was $x=y$.

Comment: Or to be more accurate.  The did *not* assume $x< y$.  The assumed $x\ne y$ and from $x \le y$ concluded that $x < y$.  And $x<y$ when compared to $y \le x$ was shown to be incompatible.  ... Whereas your argument was *also* to conclude that $x <y$ but to *not* compare that to $y \le x$, but instead to take $x\ne y$ to $y\le x$ and conclude $y < x$.  Both methods are equivalent.

Comment: Hmmm.  on fourth reading, in the "assume x < y" there is an implied WOLOG.  Other wise their proof *isnt* valid: "We have three options a) x=y b) x< y c) y< x.  Assume not a).  That leaves b)or c).  Assume b).  That leads to a contradict.  So our assumption of not a) was wrong." ....Um... they never considered option c).  They must show that leads to a contradiction as well.  Or show that it is wolog the same as invalid b).

Comment: @fleablood  but hang on. What happens to the original assumption $x\le y$ and $y \le x$? If we assume $x<y$ aren't we assuming the same thing yet again?

Comment: @fleablood .  So... 1) op’s proof is obviously perfectly correct 2) I couldn’t even be sure the reference proof actually mapped to something correct at the level of words (the idea is clearly correct and the same as OP’s). 3) You seem to have figured out the precise logic of it after four tries and concluded it is valid...The upshot I think is OP’s proof is the same proof but written much better.

Comment: Actually, on five or six readings (I'm actually making up the numbers) I think the author's proof isn't valid unless you accept a WOLOG but considering such a basic level of this proof, *justifying* the wolog probably isnt valid.  At heart they are the same proof but the OPs is better and the author's has at least one demonstrable (but easily fixed) flaw.

Comment: "What happens to the original assumption x≤y and y≤x?" Well, technically those aren't assumptions.  They are given facts.  By trichotomy we have exactly one of x=y, x<y, y< x.  If we *assume* $x\ne y$ we have x<y or y< x. The author assumes that those two are equivalent and more or less the same so it doesnt matter which one of those two we assume. That's.... well, vague and unconvincing...And it certainly *seems* wrong. They are complete opposites after all! But there's nothing other than labeling to tell x and y apart. If we assume they are not equal we might as well assume the smaller is x.

Comment: Well, I've come to a point where I cannot absorb any more information (I'm a first year undergraduate). What should I do the proof given by the authors?  Should I email them regarding this? Btw, this is the textbook "A basic course in analysis" by "Ajit Kumar and S. Kumaresan".

Comment: Alright, it's *not* a good proof.  My proof would be simplest.  By trichotomy exactly on of $x=y; x<y;y< x$ is true. If $y<x$ then neither $x<y$ nor $x=y$ is possible so $x \le y$ (which means $x<y$ or $x=y$) is not true. That contradicts our hypothesis so $y< x$ is not an option.  Likewise $x<y$ means neither $y<x$ nor $x=y$ and that contradicts our hypothesis $y\le x$.  That means $x=y$ is the only possible option (or our hypothesis are not compatible).  (Yet $x=y$ implies both our hypothesis so they are compatible).

Comment: "What should I do the proof given by the authors?"  Move on.  You've proven it to your satisfaction.  The proof is *flawed* but it is more or less correct.  You can write to the authors but you'll have to explain your concern and as you've reached you absorbtion point that might prove frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

> They say "Assume that we have $x<y$"

You are taking it out of context. The full statement is:

> We claim that $x=y$. If false, then either, $x<y$ or $y<x$ by law of trichotomy. Assume that we have $x<y$.

"If false, then..." implies "If $x\ne y$, then either, $x<y$ or $y<x$ by law of trichotomy. Assume that we have $x<y$."

The book's this statement corresponds to your statement:
"Suppose $x≠y$. Then $x≤y$ and $y≤x$ reduces to $x<y$ and $y<x$. But both inequalities $x<y$ and $y<x$ cannot hold together at the same time due to trichotomy."

The law of trichotomy: "Every real number is negative, $0$, or positive." So the book is using "OR" for each case: $x<y$ or $x>y$ separately, while you are using "OR" indirectly, that is by negating "AND".

> Did they deduce it or assume it?

They deduced it from the assumption $x\ne y$. See below with my comments inside brackets:

We claim that $x=y$. If false ($\color{blue}{x\ne y}$), then either, $x<y$ or $y<x$ by law of trichotomy. Assume that we have $x<y$. Since $y≤x$ (original statement: $\color{green}{x\le y}$ $\color{magenta}{\text{and}}$ $\color{red}{y\le x}$), either $x=y$ or $y<x$. Neither can be true, since we assumed $\color{blue}{x≠y}$ and hence concluded $x<y$ from the first inequality $x\le y$ ($\color{green}{x≤y}$). Hence we conclude that the second inequality ($\color{red}{y\le x}$) cannot be true (because of $\color{magenta}{\text{and}}$), a contradiction. Thus our assumption that $x≠y$ is not tenable.

Comment: Note: there is an implied wolog.  They assumed $x \ne y$.  They then have two options i) x< y or ii) y< x.  They make a second assumption i) and get a contradiction.  Then *without even considering* option ii) the concluded their *first* assumption, not their second, assumption was wrong.

Comment: @fleablood, you are right, I assume they implied it is proved similarly, though they must have stated it explicitly...

Comment: It took me four readings to catch it.  The wolog *is* valid but considering the fundamental level of this proof isn't helpful.

Comment: @fleablood, yes, I agree, and I can understand Ashish K cutting the Gordian knot.

Answer (score 1):

Their argument:

Given $x \le y$ and $y \le x$.

Assume $x \ne y$.

$x\le y$ means $x=y$ or $x < y$.  We ruled out $x=y$ so that leaves $x < y$.  Stick a pin in that.

$y \le x$ means that $y=x$ or $y < x$. Remove the pin and compare with $x < y$.  Neither $y =x$ nor $y < x$ is compatible with $x < y$.

So we have a contradiction.

So $x =y$.

Your argument:

Given $x \le y$ and $y \le x$.

Assume $x \ne y$.

$x\ne y$ means $x=y$ or $x < y$.  We ruled out $x=y$ so that leaves $x < y$.

$y \le x$ means that $y=x$ or $y < x$. We ruled out $y=x$ so that leaves $y < x$.

$x < y$ and $y<x$ are mutually incompatible.

So we have a contradiction.

So $x =y$

====

Both your arguments are valid.

They took a "$x<y$" to a Contradiction fight and you took a "$x \ne y$" the the same contradiction fight.  They were both equally good weapons.

....

But I prefer your method.  It's more symmetric which aesthtically pleases me and I find more convincing.

The one thing they did that is both better and worse than what you did, is the *really* went to the basic axiomatic deductions:  They *spelled out* that $x \le y$ means $x=y$ or $x < y$ and if we had assumed that $x\ne y$ then we deduce $x < y$ whereas you took it as obvious.

It's better in that it is pure axiomatic deduction.  It's worse in that it is hard to read as it is easy to get lost in the tedium.

But I like that you used the *same* argument for $x \le y\implies x < y$ and $y \le x \implies y < x$ whereas I dislike that they used *different* $x \le y\implies x <y$ and $x<y \land y \le x$ are incompatible arguments.

Comment: On line 4, shouldn't $x\ne y$ be $x \le y$?

Comment: Btw, the way you phrase it is certainly better than the authors did. "Assume x<y" was the thing that boggled me.

Comment: Argh  Yes.  typo.

Comment: "ne" and "le" are just a keystroke apart!

Comment: The "Assume x<y" should be read as "Of our two options; x< y or y < x, we'll arbitrarily assume x < y".  If we put it that way is it better and... wait... you have a point.  They never said ... well, since x<y must be false we have to assume y < x and ... They implied without stating a WOLOG.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a clarification on proof done by the authors. They say "Assume that we have $x < y$" and on another line they say "hence concluded $x < y$ from the first inequality $x ≤ y$". Did they deduce it or assume it?

They *deduce* it from $x \le y$ and the assumption $x \not = y$

But yes, their proof is quite confusing. I've read it over about $4$ times now, and tried to sketch their lines of reasoning, and concluded that the part

> Assume that we have  $x <y$'

is better taken out (indeed, the presence of this very sentence seems to be exactly what confused you as well!).

That is, it seems like they used this line to set up a proof by cases (see line 5 in outline below), where they show that both $x<y$ and $y<x$ would lead to a contradiction ... but then changed strategy in the middle of the proof, and ended up showing that since you can *conclude* (rather than *assume*) $x < y$ from the first inequality $x \le y$ together with the assumption $x \not = y$, you end up contradicting the second inequality.

To be rather technical and formal ... I think that in the middle of the proof they switched strategies from:

$1. x \le y$ (Premise)

$2. y \le x$ (Premise)

$3. x \not = y$ (Assumption)

$4. x < y \lor y < x$ (by 3 and Trichotomy)

$5. x < y$ (Assumption)

$6. \bot$ (between 2 and 5)

$7. y < x$ (Assumption)

$8. \bot$ (between 1 and 7)

$9. \bot$ (between 4, 5-6, and 7-8)

$10. x = y$ (3-9)

to something like:

$1. x \le y$ (Premise)

$2. y \le x$ (Premise)

$3. x \not = y$ (Assumption)

$4. x < y \ xor \ y < x$ (3 and trichotomy)

$5. y < x \lor x = y$ (from 2)

$6. x < y$ (from 1 and 3)

$7. y \not < x$ (from 4,6)

$8. \neg  (y < x \ xor \ x = y)$ (from 3 and 7)

$9. \neg y \le x$ (from 8, 4, and fact that 4 follows from 2)

$10. \bot$ (2 and 9)

$11. x = y$ (3-10)

But even that is not very clean (note the weird thing that happens on line 9 ...) . Indeed, even if we take out the unused line, we obtain:

> Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $x \le y$ and $y ≤ x$. We claim
>   that $x = y$. If false, then either, $x < y$ or $y < x$ by law of
>   *trichotomy*. Since $y ≤ x$, either $x = y$ or $y < x$. Neither can be true, since we assumed $x \not= y$ and
>   hence concluded $x < y$ from the first inequality $x ≤ y$. Hence we
>   conclude that the second inequality cannot be true, a contradiction.
>   Thus our assumption that $x \not= y$ is not tenable.

... which follows the second outline ... but is still not very readable.

... *NOT* a great example of how to write proofs!

I think your proof is far more clear! Good job, and good for you for noticing that something very funky was happening in the provided proof!